# Set up Okta authentication for jupyterhub

Tags: okta, jupyterhub

I have set up an internal deployment of jupyterhub using the zero-to-jupyterhub guide. I'd like to have it authenticated via Okta, but I don't see okta listed on the authentication documentation page. Has anyone successfully gotten jupyterhub authenticating via Okta?